# Unable to mock config value in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I have 3 files

config.js

```
const envs = {
  val1: process.env.val1 || 'testval1',
  val2: process.env.val2 || 500,
  val3: process.env.val3 || 'testval3',
  val4: process.env.val4,
  val5: process.env.val5,
}

export { envs };
```

function.js

```
import { envs } from './config.js'

const { val2 } = envs; 
export async function doSomethingWithVal2() {...}
```

function.test.js

```
import { envs } from './config.js'
import { doSomethingWithVal2 } from './function.js'

jest.mock('./config.js');
jest.replaceProperty(envs, 'val2', 2);

describe('tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('performs some func', async () => {
    doSomethingWithVal2();
  });
});
```

When I console log val3 in doSomethingWithVal3, it is still coming up as 500, and not being replaced with 2.

Answer (score 0):

You want to mock the object that's being exported from `config.js`:

```
jest.mock("./config", () => ({
  envs: {
    val2: 2,
  },
}));
```

Or for this case, you can instruct Jest to override your env variables

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setEnvVars.js'],
  // ... other configurations
};
```

And `jest.setEnvVars.js` content would be:

```
process.env.val2 = 2;
```